# parse error on input ‘=’ Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block? e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'

Tags: haskell

in haskell, I get this error, and the tabulation is correct as I think

```
main = do
 archivo <- openFile "09septiembre2019.txt" ReadMode
 contenido  <- hGetContents archivo
 let lineas = lines String archivo
      registros = filter filtrarRenglones lineas
      matrizHorarios = map words registros
      matrizHorariosFiltrada = map (map (filter (`notElem` "\"\""))) matrizHorarios
      tuplas = map hacerTuplas matrizHorariosFiltrada
      diaFecha = map (unirStrings . take 1) tuplas
      horarios = map (tomarTuplas . drop 1) tuplas
      horasSumadas = map (map sumarHoras) horarios
      horasAcumuladas = map sum horasSumadas
      horasNormalizadas = map normalizar horasAcumuladas
      stringHoras = map show horasNormalizadas
      resultado = zip diaFecha stringHoras
      stringRegistrosEmpleados = map mostrarResultado resultado
      intCantidadEmpleados = length $ filter buscarCantEmpleados lineas
      stringCantidadEmpleados = ["Total de empleados listados: " ++ show intCantidadEmpleados]
      floatHorasAcumuladas = fromIntegral (sum horasAcumuladas) / 60
      stringHorasAcumuladas =  ["\nCantidad de horas acumuladas en el mes: " ++ show floatHorasAcumuladas ++ " hs"]
      floatHorasHombre =  floatHorasAcumuladas / fromIntegral intCantidadEmpleados
      stringHorasHombre = ["\nCantidad de horas/hombre en el mes: " ++ show floatHorasHombre ++ " hs"]
      intAvgHorasHombre = floatHorasHombre / 20
      stringAvgHorasHombre = ["\nPromedio diario de horas/hombre: " ++ show intAvgHorasHombre ++ " hs"]
      informe = stringRegistrosEmpleados ++ stringCantidadEmpleados ++ stringHorasAcumuladas ++ stringHorasHombre ++ stringAvgHorasHombre
 putStrLn $ unlines informe          
 hClose archivo
```

and the error is:
parse error on input ‘=’
Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'

Comment: You should indent the `registros = `, etc. at the same column as the `lineas = ...`

Comment: I already tried to do that, but it doesn't work either, and I get the same error.

Comment: if I move all lines one space to the left (so removing one space) that are supposed to be covered by the `let` clause, then I get a lot of "Variable not defined" errors, but these are different: in that case the compiler can make sense out of the expression, and simply is missing the functions you have (probably) defined but not used.

Comment: exactly what error do you get when you move these 21 lines one column to the left?

Comment: I get the same error: `parse error on input ‘=’Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'`

Comment: but did you move *all* the lines one column to the left? Normally the error was on the `registros =` line, if you move that one one column to the left, then it will complain about the next one, so `matrizHorarios =`. That's why you need to move all the ones for the `let` clause one to the left.

Comment: here I answer you, in Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's reproduce your problem with something that we can easily fully compile:

```
main = do
  i <- return 2
  j <- return 4
  let sum = i + j
       mult = i * j
  putStrLn $ "Sum: " ++ (show sum)
  putStrLn $ "Multiplication: " ++ (show mult)
```

If I try to load this file on the ghci:

```
λ> :l 69859274-2.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 69859274-2.hs, interpreted )

69859274-2.hs:5:13: error:
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
  |
5 |        mult = i * j
  |             ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Fixing it:

```
main = do
  i <- return 2
  j <- return 4
  let sum = i + j
      mult = i * j
  putStrLn $ "Sum: " ++ (show sum)
  putStrLn $ "Multiplication: " ++ (show mult)
```

And loading again:

```
λ> :l 69859274-2.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 69859274-2.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
λ> main
Sum: 6
Multiplication: 8
```

Notice I am using two spaces columns. You are using one space columns.

Using an abridged version of your code:

```
main = do
 archivo <- openFile "09septiembre2019.txt" ReadMode
 contenido  <- hGetContents archivo
 let lineas = lines String archivo
     registros = filter filtrarRenglones lineas
     matrizHorarios = map words registros
     matrizHorariosFiltrada = map (map (filter (`notElem` "\"\""))) matrizHorarios
     tuplas = map hacerTuplas matrizHorariosFiltrada
     // all other bindings starting at the same column as this comment...
     // ....
 putStrLn $ unlines informe          
 hClose archivo
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, i move all the lines to the left, I stay like this:

```
main = do
 archivo <- openFile "09septiembre2019.txt" ReadMode
 contenido  <- hGetContents archivo
 let lineas = lines String archivo
 registros = filter filtrarRenglones lineas
 matrizHorarios = map words registros
 matrizHorariosFiltrada = map (map (filter (`notElem` "\"\""))) matrizHorarios
 tuplas = map hacerTuplas matrizHorariosFiltrada
 diaFecha = map (unirStrings . take 1) tuplas
 horarios = map (tomarTuplas . drop 1) tuplas
 horasSumadas = map (map sumarHoras) horarios
 horasAcumuladas = map sum horasSumadas
 horasNormalizadas = map normalizar horasAcumuladas
 stringHoras = map show horasNormalizadas
 resultado = zip diaFecha stringHoras
 stringRegistrosEmpleados = map mostrarResultado resultado
 intCantidadEmpleados = length $ filter buscarCantEmpleados lineas
 stringCantidadEmpleados = ["Total de empleados listados: " ++ show intCantidadEmpleados]
 floatHorasAcumuladas = fromIntegral (sum horasAcumuladas) / 60
 stringHorasAcumuladas =  ["\nCantidad de horas acumuladas en el mes: " ++ show floatHorasAcumuladas ++ " hs"]
 floatHorasHombre =  floatHorasAcumuladas / fromIntegral intCantidadEmpleados
 stringHorasHombre = ["\nCantidad de horas/hombre en el mes: " ++ show floatHorasHombre ++ " hs"]
 intAvgHorasHombre = floatHorasHombre / 20
 stringAvgHorasHombre = ["\nPromedio diario de horas/hombre: " ++ show intAvgHorasHombre ++ " hs"]
 informe = stringRegistrosEmpleados ++ stringCantidadEmpleados ++ stringHorasAcumuladas ++ stringHorasHombre ++ stringAvgHorasHombre
 putStrLn $ unlines informe          
 hClose archivo
```

and I have the same mistake

Comment: This doesn't compile

Comment: But you should not move these to the same column as the `let`, but the same column as the `lineas = `. so four columns more to the right... Not the `putStrLn` and `hClose` line, since these do not belong to the `let` clause.

Comment: That’s it, it worked, I didn’t understand your apology, thank you very much!